# How to assign a new ascii key code value

Tags: javascript

If the user press `enter` key, it should behave as he is pressing the `esc` key.

```
function OnEditorKeyPress(editor, e) {
    if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 13) {
        e.htmlEvent.keyCode = 27;
        //treeList.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

But the value 13 remains same after `e.htmlEvent.keyCode = 27;` this statement also. How to assign a new value or any other alternative method is there to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't visit at a page which mess up my keyboard, please don't try this.

Comment: why would you want to do something like that.. dont you think that would confuse users of your site...?

Comment: That's the reason why this properties are readonly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties of the event object are read only (including `KeyCode`), so you can't do such of thing. Why you can't do something like this?

```
function OnEditorKeyPress(editor, e) {
   //If user press enter or escape
   if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 13 || e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 27) // correct comparison operation
   {
      treeList.CancelEdit();
      e.htmlEvent.preventDefault
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you insist, read this on the Mozilla Forums: [Need to override key pressed replacing keycode](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1950767)

Comment: Tom is right. This approach is better and also don't forget to `e.htmlEvent.preventDefault();` after `CancelEdit` to prevent any default behavior of `Enter` or `Esc`.

Comment: @TomSarduy, I accompolished my goal by using the '_cancelEvent(event)' function as you refer the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code helps you in stopping the default functionality of "Enter" button However you can enter your code to do whatever you want when user press "enter". Though Implementing ESC functionality on ENTER will not be appreciated.

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/Z4dgr/11/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayunicode(e){
e.preventDefault();
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
alert(unicode)
}
</script>
<form>
Enter from keyboard <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="1" onkeypress="displayunicode(event); this.select()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Tom's answer here is what you need.

```
function OnEditorKeyPress(editor, e) {
   //If user press enter or escape
   if (e.htmlEvent.keyCode == 13 || e.htmlEvent.keyCode = 27) 
   {
      treeList.CancelEdit();
      e.htmlEvent.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried with 'e.htmlEvent.preventDefault()'. It is working fine but I used the '_cancelEvent(event)' functon to accompolish my goal. Thanks.